# How to select a value in a table and if it doesn't exist another value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to find a solution for this, but most other answers don't work.

I have a page to translate my website, with mySQL all the texts are echo'd (in an overflow:auto of course, so that the whole page isn't filled with text), and I want it to echo all the texts which are already translated in the translation-language. All the texts from the websites which don't have a translation yet, should have "English" as the chosen language to display. I have tried all kinds of things, but I can't get it to work.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `website` WHERE language='$_SESSION[translate]' GROUP BY name");
```

is the query which I currently have. This returns all the translated values in the translation language, which is fine, but it doesn't display ALL the 'name'-values and it should display all the other 'name'-values in English, because they don't have a translation yet. But I have no idea how to do it, and JOINS only seems to work for multiple tables.

Comment: I don't understand what it is youre asking here

Comment: The problem is that I have a page for my website to translate it. All the text from the website is stored in a table in the database, where all the texts have a name. At the translation page, all the non-translated texts should be displayed in English and all the translated ones in the translation-language. But the names should be distinct, this is the problem. So you have:       index  -  English    -   Hello, this is a website.             index - Dutch     - Hello, this is a website.            It should just display the Dutch one, because Index can't be a duplicate and only be once there.

Answer (score 0):

You can join a table with itself:

```
SELECT w1.name, IFNULL(w2.value, w1.value) AS value
FROM website AS w1
LEFT JOIN website AS w2 ON w1.name = w2.name AND w2.language = '$_SESSION[translate]'
WHERE w1.language = 'english'
```

The outer join result in a `NULL` value when there's no translation, and `IFNULL` then uses the English version as a default.

Comment: Could you explain your answer? I understand a lot of the basic functions, but the JOIN function is something which I really don't like when I read it, because it's hard to understand.

Comment: You really need to learn about joins, since they're essential to SQL programming. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ is a good tutorial

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great tutorial and cleaner than the one from W3schools. I hope that it will help me to find out the answer for this. Could you explain what w2 and w1 are in your answer?

Comment: They're aliases for `website`. Since you're accessing the same table twice, you need to use aliases to distinguish them.